# solr indexing through curl using c++

Tags: c++, curl, solr

I am tried this but it is not working let me know what is wrong with the following code:

```
static const char *postthis="[{\"id\":\"4000\", \"to\":\"Life is to.\", \"cc\":\"unknown cc\", \"subject\":\"Life is subject\"}]";
    static const char *postthis1= "http://192.168.0.164:8983/solr/collection1/update?wt=json&commit=true ";
    static const char *postthis2= "'Content-type: application/json'";
    struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,postthis1 );
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postthis);

        list = curl_slist_append(list, "-H");
        list = curl_slist_append(list, postthis2);
        list = curl_slist_append(list, "-d");
        /* if we don't provide POSTFIELDSIZE, libcurl will strlen() by
        itself */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(postthis));
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */ 
        if(res != CURLE_OK){
            logger.LogError("curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
```

with the above code I am getting response on terminal window as :

```
   {"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":9}}
```

which is response of above request.

and in solr log I  am getting following things:

```
INFO  - 2016-05-19 11:22:10.778; [   x:collection1] org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
INFO  - 2016-05-19 11:22:10.779; [   x:collection1] org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; No uncommitted changes. Skipping IW.commit.
INFO  - 2016-05-19 11:22:10.781; [   x:collection1] org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; SolrIndexSearcher has not changed - not re-opening: org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher
INFO  - 2016-05-19 11:22:10.783; [   x:collection1] org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; end_commit_flush
INFO  - 2016-05-19 11:22:10.784; [   x:collection1] org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update params={commit=true&[{"id":"4001", "from":"Life is to", "to":"unknown cc", "subject":"Life is subject"}]=&wt=json} {commit=} 0 8
```

Actual curl command is :

```
 curl http://192.168.0.164:8983/solr/collection1/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"id":"450", "to":"Life is .", "cc":"unknown", "subject":"Life"}]'
```

it is working fine for indexing.

Comment: What do you mean "it is working fine for indexing"?  Does the actual curl command you gave work?  I am surprised you don't need to specify some sort of encoding for the data.  It appears your data is getting truncated.  What is the value of strlen?  Does curl have some internal buffer size?

Comment: Yes the actual curl command is working . I am new to this curl and solr I found this code on some site and trying it for my problem.